# How to merge an IQueryable list into another existing IQueryable source in c#?

Tags: c#, linq

Below is my code.

```
public IQueryable GetCarsByStatusId(List<int> statusIds = null)
{
  IQueryable data = null;
  if(statusIds == null)
  {
    data = this.Context.ACRViewCars.OrderBy(x=>x.Status);
  }
  else if(statusIds != null && statusIds.Count > 0)
  {
    foreach(int id in statusIds)
    {
      var query = this.Context.ACRViewCars.Where(x => x.StatusId == id);
      if(query != null)
      {
        //What to do here; I have no idea
      }
    }
  }
  return data;
}
```

The scenario is: I have a list and using this, I want to retrieve data from IQueryable source (this.Context.ACRViewCars). And if data found, I want to merge the records in one single IQueryable object (data). Can anyone help please?

Comment: The link you are referring to, contains 2 different IQueryables (q1 & q2) and lately they were merged. But in my case, I want to obtain IQueryables using a list and the list can contains 100s or 1000s records. In that case, how should I use the referred link's solution. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While there are [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902082/how-to-merge-result-iqueryablet-together) that answer your *specific* question, why not just do this in one hit instead of merging multiple results?

```
return this.Context.ACRViewCars.Where(x => statusIds.Contains(x.StatusId));
```

Assuming the query provider is dealing in SQL, this is usually translated to something like:

```
SELECT StatusId, x, y, z
FROM ACRViewCars
WHERE StatusId IN (1, 4, 6);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am already using this. However, I am marking your answer as "Answer". :)

Answer (score 0):

if you can not use `IQueryable<T>`, a way to do this:

```
public IEnumerable<IQueryable> GetCarsByStatusId(List<int> statusIds = null)
{
    if (statusIds == null)
    {
        yield return this.Context.ACRViewCars.OrderBy(x => x.Status);
    }
    else if (statusIds != null && statusIds.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (int id in statusIds)
        {
            yield return this.Context.ACRViewCars.Where(x => x.StatusId == id);
        }
    }
}
```